# How to do passwordless authentication through magic link automation using mobile automation with Appium and WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, android, automation, appium, webdriver-io

**Platform:** Android and iOS.

**Automation Tools:** Appium + WebdriverIO(JavaScript)

**App behavior:**

1. When I launched my app, landing page has "GET STARTED" button.
2. On clicking, redirected to the "Sign In" page which has 'Email Address' text box field and 'Sign In' button.
3. Post clicking 'Sign In' button, it will send email to entered email address with Subject: Login Link.
4. After clicking this link, I'm logged into my app.

**Q1: How to handle such scenario through this combination of tools with automation?**

I've discussed with my dev team and conveyed that it would be very difficult to do automation of email inbox through automation with considering the scope of tools.

**Q2: Is it possible to do?**

Alternative way is: They are providing me POST API, through hitting, I'll get login link in the response and on hitting I'll be able to logged in to my app directly.

But my concern is: When I starting the automation execution, it always first trigger fresh session, install and launches the app. Post launch of an app, how to hit the URL and skipping this email Address screen and bypass login directly?

**Q3: Please suggest a way of handling mobile app automation with hitting link the browser of mobile itself?**

Moreover, How to make best way of web hooks i.e. before hook in this implementation?

P.S.:

This login link is only valid for 60min. Example of login link: `https://api.xxx.com/auth/iyFJt640clXQNHIgHZSYO`

I'm beginner with mobile app automation.

Answer (score 0):

I used mailosaur to receive the email and then obtain the URL from the message that I received from there. And this wdio code to do log in through the link:

```
driver.execute('mobile: deepLink', {
      url: //URL,
    });
```

This is working on local iOS simulator but not on Browserstack devices. IDK why :(

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the best workaround for testing deeplinks with real iOS devices is:

1. Launch the Safari App

   ```
    driver.execute(
    'mobile: terminateApp,
    {
    bundleId: "Your_App_bundle_id"
    }
    );
   ```
2. Enter the deep link in the address bar
3. Confirm the notification pop-up

You can read more about it here:
https://www.headspin.io/blog/reliably-opening-deep-links-across-platforms-and-devices

Hope that helps!